# What's the Intellij equivalence to Eclipse user library?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea, dependency-management

I have been using Eclipse for many years but I hate it due to its bad performance - it freezes from time to time.

Now I am trying to use JetBrain's IntelliJ IDEA 12.1, and have some questions.

In Eclipse I use user libraries, which keep references to external jar files, and are used in project build path.

In IntelliJ I have found that the equivalence should be "Global libraries". When creating such things I have got 2 problems:

1. IntelliJ tries to copy all the jar files into my (home)/.IdeaIC12. Can I create references to those jars without creating copies?
2. When I press the plus button in Project Structure to add files or directories to libraries, IntelliJ opens a dialog at once and begin to create a tree view of my whole file system - this takes a couple of minutes, then IntelliJ simply does not response. And when I add another jars/directories, it freeze again. How to disable this automatic searching process, but tell it a directory directly?

Perhaps Maven is a better solution but I cannot use it for some reasons.
My computer has 4GB RAM, running Windows XP 32bit.

Comment: **1**. Copy is made to prevent jars locking, add `-Didea.jars.nocopy=true` into [.vmoptions](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793) to disable this behavior. **2**. It may be caused by the slow/disconnected network drives, related issue: [IDEA-56075](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-56075).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I have read the links you provided. It seems no solution for the second problem, isn't it? Then IntelliJ cannot be used on systems with slow network drives at all.

Comment: You should attach a [thread dump](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23348667) to the issue.